# How to remove the sockjs-node error for a asp.net core angular application?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, sockjs

I have a **asp.net core angular** application. I deleted the `ClientApp` folder in that application and created a new angular 8.1 beta app using `ng new` command. The application can be run, but I see a lot of `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in the browser.

What should I do to remove these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the exact same problem as you.  The issue is the live reloading when changes occur.  To fix this update the ng serve script and set the public-host option.

I am serving my angular app from the /app1 route so my ng serve looks like

ng serve --base-href=/app1/ --serve-path=/ --public-host=localhost:5001/app1